# JavaScript - new RegExp stop escaping

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I tell JavaScript new RegExp to STOP escaping my wildcard character?  I am creating a RegExp like this...

```
var matcher = new RegExp('brake*',i');
```

and when I console log the matcher var I get

```
/brake\*/i
```

I am trying to create the RegExp so it matches the word brake with ANYTHING after it.

Comment: The \* is causing it not to match I think.  Shouldn't it just be /brake*/\i to match the word brake with any string following it case insensitive

Comment: _"so it matches the word brake with ANYTHING after it"_ - then why are you currently trying to match `brak` with zero to infinity `e` after it ...? You'll have to specify that _anything_ you are looking for - like a `.` for "any character", and that 0 to multiple times - `.*`

Comment: I'm terrible at RegEx.  Can anyone show example of how to create new RegExp that would match "brake" with anything after it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you just want to check if a string _contains_ the word `brake`, you can use `indexOf` (apply `toLowerCase` first, if you want to search regardless of case.) Or do you want to _capture_ `brake` and what comes behind it? Then you will need `()` to create a _grouping_ pattern. Last but not least, what exactly do you want to match/capture? _Anything_ after brake, till the end of the string? Or actual _letters_, so in fact words beginning with `brake` ...?

Comment: Like this: `\bbrake\b.*`?

Comment: Go for `brake[\S\s]*` which matches _brake_ plus anything after it until end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star `*` is not a wildcard. It signifies 0 or more of the preceding token.

So your current pattern `/break*/` matches "brea" + 0 or more occurrences of "k", for example "brea" or "breakkkkkkkkkk".

You are looking for the dot `.` which represents any character except line breaks, which you can then combine with `*` to match an infinite number of these "any" characters.

So given the string "I ate breakfast this morning", the pattern `/break./` would match "breakf", while the pattern `/break.*/` would match "breakfast this morning".

```js
const string = 'I ate breakfast this morning'

const pattern = new RegExp('break.*', 'i')

const result = string.match(pattern)

document.querySelector('p').textContent = result
```

```html
<p>
```

Comment: brake not break :p